# Let $P_1,P_2, \ldots,P_n$ be $n$ arbitrary points of the plane.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $P_1,P_2, \ldots,P_n$ be $n$ arbitrary points of the plane. If a variable point $P$ is confined to a closed bounded set $E$, show that the product $$\prod_{k=1}^n \overline{PP_k}$$
attains its maximum if $P$ is some point of the boundary of $E$, where $\overline{PP_k}$ denotes the distance between points $P_k$ and $P$ $(k=1,2,\ldots,n)$.

I am trying to use the maximum modulus principle I see that the domain is bounded which is a requirement but I am not seeing how to apply the product to the principle.

Comment: Well, what is your conceptual argument?

Comment: Do you know what are compact sets and continuous functions? I presume you don't because you tagged this under complex analysis which is odd, but with this machinery your answer is very easy.

Comment: this is trivial if you can use [maximum modulus principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle) in complex analysis.

Comment: Ok thanks i will look into the maximum modulus principle @achille hui